# Get the UIBezierPath or CGPath from CGContextRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a bezier path inside the current graphics context that I want to store as a UIBezierPath or CGPath. Do you know how to get the path out of a CGContextRef?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy the context's current path using `CGContextCopyPath`.

There is no function that copies the clipping path.  Indeed, the clipping region won't be defined by a path if you've used `CGContextClipToMask`.

Comment: I drawn a image on Context, now I want to get CGPath from the context, I tried to get, by using the CGContextCopy, but its not working

Comment: If you drew a bitmap image into your context (like with `CGContextDrawImage` for example), Core Graphics won't convert that to a path for you.  If you created a path in your context and then stroked or filled it (for example with `CGContextFillPath`), then you need to copy the path **before** stroking or filling it, because Core Graphics clears its current path after drawing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CGContextCopyPath` function:

```
CGPathRef myPath = CGContextCopyPath(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4.0 and higher

You can just use for coping the path.

```
let copy = context.path
```